# Unable to update view on model property change in jquery event in angular component

Tags: jquery, angular

I am having some wired issue while updating view.

Scenario :

I have declared jquery button click event on oninit of angular component.
On click event i am updating model value and binding on view
But when i click button its not updated in view.
If I used same in angular click  event(create) its shows updated value in view.

Not sure what is going wrong here.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  messagee: string;

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef){
    this.messagee = 'Set in constructor'
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#buttionid').click(function(){

        //this message never displayed in 
        this.messagee ="Hello on button click handler in jquery"; 

        $('#lblMessage').text(this.messagee);
      })
     });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

    var jquery = document.createElement('script');
    jquery.type = 'text/javascript';
    jquery.src = './node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js';
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(jquery);

  }

  title = 'jquerydemo';

  create () {
    this.messagee ="I am  called from button";
  }

}
```

View : app.component.html

```
<button id='buttionid' type="button">Jquery click</button>
<br/>
<button (click)="create()">Angular click</button>

<br/>By finding span id in jquery :  <span id="lblMessage"> </span>

<div>using interpoation method :{{messagee}}</div>
```

This is demo application where i tried to updated model on UI. In actual application i am using jsTree. In jsTree application they have jquery event.

```
$('#jstree')
  // listen for event
  .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var i, j, r = [];
    for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {

     //Unable to passed value from this event to UI or any other compoents
      r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);

    }
    $('#event_result').html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
  })
  // create the instance
  .jstree();
```

Comment: `this` inside `$('#buttionid').click(function(){` is not the class, it is the element the event occurred on. Not sure why you are even using jQuery in an angular app. They don't mix well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `$('#buttionid').click` event inside `ngAfterViewInit()` of `AppComponent` is a lifecycle callback. Angular calls it after the root component and it's children have been rendered and it should fit for your purpose.

As comment from the @charlietfl `this` will not be the object of you class. It will be object of button. To solve issue you can change normal `function` To `arrow function` like shown below.

See also https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  messagee: string;

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef){
    this.messagee = 'Set in constructor'
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

      $('#buttionid').click(() => {

        //this message never displayed in 
        this.messagee ="Hello on button click handler in jquery"; 

        $('#lblMessage').text(this.messagee);
      });
     
  

    var jquery = document.createElement('script');
    jquery.type = 'text/javascript';
    jquery.src = './node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js';
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(jquery);

  }

  title = 'jquerydemo';

  create () {
    this.messagee ="I am  called from button";
  }

}
```

Comment: Still a problem with `this` context in the jQuery event handler

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for pointing that out. I’ve updated answer and suggested to use `arrow function` so it would access `this` as `Component` object.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
     const self = this:
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#buttionid').click(function(){

        //this message never displayed in 
        self.messagee ="Hello on button click handler in jquery"; 

        $('#lblMessage').text(self.messagee);
      })
     });
  }
```

or

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#buttionid').click(() => {

        //this message never displayed in 
        this.messagee ="Hello on button click handler in jquery"; 

        $('#lblMessage').text(this.messagee);
      })
     });
  }
```

Inside the `function(){}` (non arrow functions) the context of the `this` keyword is not the same as inside `() => {}`